# set and subset question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given  a nonempty set S, we select a fixed subset $S_0\subseteq S$ and use it to define two functions on the set of all subsets of $S$:

1. $f(A)=A\cup S_0$
2. $g(A)=A\setminus S_0$

For what choices of $S_0$ do these functions commute?

1. Only for $S_0=\varnothing$? or
2. Only for $S_0=S$? or
3. For all $S_0$?

Comment: You have three options. Test each option with an example.

Comment: first option: f(A)=A , g(A) = A

Comment: second option: f(A) = A ∪ S, g(A) = A / S, i am confused this with the third option actually,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that the functions commute if for every $A$, $f(g(A))=g(f(A))$, that is $$(A\cup S_0)\setminus S_0=(A\setminus S_0)\cup S_0.$$

The choices for which the functions **don't** commute can be found by testing the case where $S=\{a,b,c\}$. The choice where the functions do commute is easily provable.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, i followed your explanation, the answer would be the first one, is that correct? thank you

Comment: Yes, the first one is true, the others false.

Answer (score -1):

$gf(A)=g(A\cup S_0)=(A\cup S_0)\setminus S_0=A\setminus S_0$

$fg(A)=(A\setminus S_0)\cup S_0=A$

1 -true

Comment: Your calculation of $fg(A)$ is false. $A=\varnothing$ and $S_0\neq\varnothing$ gives $fg(A)=S_0\neq A$.